# One half of my rig won't connect to my mesh

Tags: rigging

This is my first time making a model and while rigging I can't seem to get the left side of my rig to move with the mesh.

[image: rig with one bone not connecting with mesh]

[image]

[image: x and y axis clicked]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Thanks! I just added the file

Comment: After the upload, you need to copy the link that the upload page gives you and post it here so we can access the file.

Comment: Ok did that sorry this is so different

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly name your limb bones, like *arm_L* and *arm_R*, if you want the mirrored mesh to be controlled by the armature, that said your mesh is not only mirrored on X, it is also mirrored on Y, so it still won't work, you either need to apply a mirror on Y, or even apply on both X and Y, unless you have a reason not to?

Comment: Thanks so much! I just named the limb bones but how would I do the mirroring if its not too much trouble? I don't fully get what you mean when you say "is not only mirrored on X, it is also mirrored on Y" and then " apply a mirror on Y, or even apply on both X and Y"

Comment: why don't you apply the Mirror modifier at least on Y? and make sure that you delete the face on the back of the head

Comment: On the modifier I have both y and x clicked on the axis button is that not it? Also I don't know how to make the texture painting not cause that face on the back of the head im still trying to figure that out lol. Here ill add a pic of what I thought it was

Comment: Apply your modifier, or, if for some reason you want to keep a Mirror on X, duplicate your modifier, activate Y only on the first one, X on the second one, apply the fist one