# Rig stretches mesh and texture painting is on both sides

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

This is my first model and I'm having a problem with the rig stretching the mesh and my texture painting is on both sides by that I mean the face is on both sides of the head. I don't know if thats because everything is mirrored.
[image]
[image: Mesh is stretching]

[image: another stretch]

Comment: As @moonboots answered in your [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302610/one-half-of-my-rig-wont-connect-to-my-mesh) you still have the mirror modifier on your object and it's mirrored in both the X and Y directions. Uncheck the 'Y' on the modifier panel and Apply it by hovering the mouse over the modifier and hitting Ctrl-A in Object mode. That should fix both the rig stretching and allow you to paint just on one side of the head.

Comment: Ah thank you so much I didn't fully understand what they meant and how I would do something like that!

Comment: In your case,looking at the front of your model, the mirror modifier mirrors the right side of the  model to the left with X selected, **including** any texture painting, but since you also had Y selected it was also mirroring the front of the model to the back, again with your texture paint. That was also affecting the operation of the rig.